# SQL query for each row of another table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I need to run an `INSERT` query for every `p.name` that I get from a `SELECT` in another table. What it should look like my `INSERT`?

Example:

```
INSERT into table_2 (col_1, col_2) values (value, table_1.p_1)
INSERT into table_2 (col_1, col_2) values (value, table_1.p_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into table_2 (col_1, col_2) 
Select 'some value', p_1 
from table1
```